# Get last car details from cookies

Tags: php, cookies, substring

We have car details saved in cookie

```
$_COOKIE['ymm_selected'] = {\"vehicle\":\"Alfa Romeo,Giulia,2022\",\"vehicles\":[\"Citroen,DS3,2018\",\"Citroen,C2,2006\",\"Alfa Romeo,Giulia,2022\"]}
```

I want to get a variable for current vehicle which is always the last one, in this case it is Alfa Romeo Giulia 2022

I tried the following:

```
    $cookiev = $_COOKIE['ymm_selected'];
    $vehiclef1 = get_string_between($cookiev, 'vehicles\":[\"', '\"]}');
    $vehiclef2  = preg_replace('/,[^,]*$/', '', $vehiclef1);
    $vehiclef3 =  preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', ' ', trim($vehiclef2));
```

This will give the following

Citroen DS3 2018" "Citroen C2 2006" "Alfa Romeo Giulia

I want to get the last vehicle. The vehicle is different every time so I cannot do that by counting.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Maybe better do this with `json_decode` instead of regex stuff here.

Comment: @Foobar I tried json_decode, serialize, explode but it did not solve the problem thats why I decided to do it this way

Comment: When you remove `\` its valid json that can be decoded. And you don't need serialize or explode after decoding. First answer here does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that :

```
$_COOKIE['ymm_selected'] = '{\"vehicle\":\"Alfa Romeo,Giulia,2022\",\"vehicles\":[\"Citroen,DS3,2018\",\"Citroen,C2,2006\",\"Alfa Romeo,Giulia,2022\"]}';


$formatted = stripslashes($_COOKIE['ymm_selected']);

$decoded = json_decode($formatted, true);

echo end($decoded['vehicles']);
```

Regards,